# "Low Bound Exceeds High Bound" error in Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, delphi-10.4-sydney

Currently I am in the process of migrating an application from Delphi 5 to Delphi 10. The below switch case works fine in Delphi 5 but gives

```
"Low Bound Exceeds High Bound"
```

error in Delphi 10 during compilation. If I change the value from #128 to #127 then everything works fine. I am not sure why using #128 gives an error whereas using #127 works fine.

```
var Src : PChar;
...
case Src^ of
  #128..#255 :
    begin
    end;
end;
```

Comment: It would help to have more complete code, e.g. what is Src declared as?

Comment: Pchar Src := PChar(Str); this is how Src is declared

Comment: @Devd, that is how it is assigned, but the edit I made is the simplest way to reproduce the error.

Comment: In Delphi 5, `PChar` was `PAnsiChar`. In Delphi 10, `PChar` is `PWideChar` instead. Character literals #128..#255 are subject to the [`{$HIGHCHARUNICODE}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/HIGHCHARUNICODE_directive_(Delphi)) directive.

Comment: Your real problem is that you haven't modified this code to a lccount for Unicode. Even if you make it compile it won't be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why the code you show doesn't work. I fear it is a bug!
Anyway, to have it compile, you can write it like this:

```
var Src : PChar;
...
case Src^ of
  #128, #129..#255 :
    begin
    end;
end;
```

This will have the same effect.
You can also write:

```
case Ord(Src^) of
  128..255 :
    begin
    end;
end;
```

But this second variation is annoying if you have many other cases where you have constant char. You have to modify each one by adding and Ord().

You should also have a look at the effect of [{$HIGHCHARUNICODE}](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/HIGHCHARUNICODE_directive_(Delphi)) directive.

By the way: This kind of code is - maybe - the sign that you forgot that in Delphi 5 characters are 8 bit ANSI while for Delphi 2009 and upward, the characters are 16 bit.

Comment: May I assume Delphi 9 to be Delphi 2005?

Comment: @BlurrySterk: No, fpiette means Delphi 2009 (that's when strings became Unicode). It's a very uncommon way to refer to Delphi 2009, though.

Comment: Note that following snippet will not give the same result when compiled for Delphi-5 and Delphi 10.4 `var p : PChar; s : String; begin s := #128; p := PChar(s); case p^ of  #128,#129..#255 : WriteLn(Ord(p^)); end; ReadLn; end.` And it is not a compiler bug. See also https://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/delphi-and-unicode-marco-cantu.pdf